# HTML, JQuery, Binding Handlers on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating some dom elements according to some ajax response, which I want to add js event listeners to them. The following is my code  :

```
$output = "<div><div class='recipients'><ul>";
        foreach($contacts as $contact){
        $output .= "<li>
                        <div>
                            <input class='contact-checkbox' type='checkbox' checked/>
                            <span>{$contact['dnr']['tel_no']}</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>";
        }
$output .="</ul></div></div>";
```

The above output is used here as shown (ie. $(list).html() is returning the above generated markup.)

```
$("<div id='" + filter_id + "' class='filter toggler'>" + filter_id + $(list).html() + "</div>").appendTo($('#recipient-list'));
```

After appending the element, I call a method 'bind_functions()' which binds prepared event handlers as follows :

```
function bind_functions(){

    $('.toggler').click(function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    //e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.recipients').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

The above code simply creates a a div which is wrapped around an unordered list `<ul>` with its child lists `<li>`. This element is created more than once, with the purpose of creating multiple filters. On click, they slide down to show their respective `<ul><li>` elements.

This all seems to work fine until you add more than one.. WHat happens is(very strange IMO), upon creating the  element  the first time, the event is binded and it works, when adding the second, the second element works, but the first element does not work anymore. If I add the third element, then the 1st and the 3rd(last added) elements, are listening to the event and work, but the 2nd doesnt. As you might imagine, if I add the 4th element, the 2nd and 4th element will listen to the event, whilst the 1st and third are back to not working..

What could be the cause of this. How can an element be binded to and event listener at one point, and not be, in another point in time. The generated markup all seems fine but I will also provide it here, perhaps I am missing something .

Here it is

```
<div id="Any-Female-Any" class="filter toggler">Any-Female-Any
<div class="recipients">
<ul>
  <li>
     <div>
         <input class="contact-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="">
         <span>441895324</span>
     </div>
  </li>
  <li>
     <div>
         <input class="contact-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="">
         <span>449185147</span>
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

This is whats generated in dom tree when inspecting in google

Comment: You should use delegation. BTW, this will avoid getting one handler bound for each element

Comment: Do you mean using jquery .on() rather than click ? Do you think its whats causing the problem ? Ill try it

Comment: again event delegation issue? you should search on stackoverflow, here so many questions are already answered.

Comment: Is there a particular motivation to use `bind_functions()`? Because if not, I suggest you to use the `on()`. (https://api.jquery.com/on/) It works on every element added dinammicall

Comment: @KevinCittadini no it doesn't! You still need to delegate event, `.on()` has specific syntax for that. Just replacing `.bind()` with `.on()` won't solve OP's issue

Comment: @A.Wolff: Who said "just replacing" ? I know, I didn't say that. Mine was a question and i posted a link with some more info. It's not an answer, but a comment

Comment: @KevinCittadini so my bad, misread your comment.

Comment: @A.Wolff Not a problem, I'll edit my comment and make it a little more detailed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
$(document)
  .on('click', '.toggler', function(){
    // toggler click
  })
  .on('click', '.recipients', function(){
    // recipients click
  })
;
```

There will be no need to create an call `bind_functions` function and it will handle new DOM elements created during the runtime.

Comment: @user2678538 You should aim to bind the delegated event handlers (that's what these are) to a static element (i.e. exists on page load, never gets removed or replaced) that's as close to your dynamic ones as possible. In your code you're appending to an element with the `#recipient-list` selector, so that would be a good candidate: `$('#recipient-list')` instead of `$(document)`. You'd then need to make sure the code is in a DOM ready handler though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thanks for this explanation, clear and concise! Also hsz's answer solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You would be much better off by using bind feature of jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: I did try .bind() but the problem still persists